# How to validate to accept only float values in php

Tags: php

I am looking to validate a field using php. The value to be entered in that field should be a float value. None other can be accepted. Not even integer. It should accept values like 5.2 or 4.1 and so on. Integers like 3 or 56 or 123 etc will also not be accepted. Hope it is clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [`is_float`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) in PHP.

```
<?php
if (is_float(53)) {
    echo "is float\n";
} else {
    echo "is not float\n";  //<---- This will be printed !
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100061)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. What if i want to accept a float with only one decimal point in it. Like the example i used above in my question?

Comment: The above exactly does what you are looking for. A valid float will have only 1 decimal point as far as I know ;) I will add a demo for your use.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran what about '1.2'? we get string from text field.

Answer (score 1):

[is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) will fail with strings (e.g. get or post submissions). To check if a value is numeric use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). To check for a float value, cast to an integer and check for equality:

```
function is_float_value($value) {
    return is_numeric($value) && ('' . (int)$value) !== "$value";
}

echo is_float_value("53.1") ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // yes
echo is_float_value(53.1)   ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // yes
echo is_float_value("0.0")  ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // yes
echo is_float_value(0.0)    ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // no - internally represented as 0
echo is_float_value("53")   ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // no
echo is_float_value(53)     ? "yes\n" : "no\n"; // no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x='1.23';
if(preg_match('/^(\d)*\.(\d)+$/',$x)){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'No';
}
```

You can check with regex because the value you receive from text field will be string.